# Azure AD B2C Angular front + Django Backend

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We need to create application based on Angular, Django and with integrations with Azure B2C AD.

Now, we have done part with Angular, we make request to Azure B2C, when user will be sign in, it return to angular app with `?id_token`.
And there is our problem, because frontend need to communicate with our backend written in Django. We need to secure this connections and get know who is making request.

We want to create something like that:

**angular->Azure B2C**

**Azure B2C->(with id_token)->angular**

***angular->Django(with id_token)->create session->angular(send session_key)***

**angular->Django(with session_key->angular(with requested data)**

And there is problem, we don't know how to verify that user is successfully signed in in Azure. (Part which I make italic).

Comment: You can validate your id token in you app or have a proxy server like nginx which does the validation for you and proxy passes the request to django server.

Comment: Any solution you got?

Answer (score 1):

You should get an Authorization Code from AAD B2C and not a token, as the [OAuth 2.0 authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) describes it.

So you should do:

**Angular -> Azure B2C**

**Azure B2C -> (with auth code) -> Angular**

**Angular -> Django(with auth code) -> retrieve access_token and refresh_token**

**Angular -> Django Secured API (with access_token)**

We just released our own implementation of Angular + AAD B2C (running on ASP.NET Core but the logic should be the same, you will only need to find the Django equivalent), if you want to see how to do it: https://github.com/3DSemantix/angular-asp.net-core-aad-b2c